# How do I add Builder methods to a custom IndexedSeq in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

As a simplified example, assume I want to set up an IndexedSeq that is typed specifically to use integers, like the below:

```
class IntSeq private(val ints: Seq[Int], val length: Int) extends IndexedSeq[Int]{
  def apply(idx: Int): Int = {
    if(idx < 0 || idx >= length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    ints(idx)
  }
}

object IntSeq {
   def fromSeq(seq: Seq[Int]): IntSeq = new IntSeq(seq, seq.length)

   def apply(ints: Int*): IntSeq = fromSeq(ints)
}
```

Superficially, this code seems to work in the sense that:

```
val intSeq = IntSeq(1, 2)
intSeq(1) // correctly returns the 2
```

However, if I then try to extend this IntSeq with:

```
intSeq + 3
```

I will get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: String
```

I can see that this is because the + method is in fact coming from the Predef object, which was perhaps not what I expected.

What is missing from IntSeq that would allow the Builder functions to be used?
Do I need to add/ define a Builder? 
How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the immutable IndexedSeq or Seq in general does not have a `+` method. It only has `:+` and `+:` as you can append and prepend to a Seq.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but actually this is also true for mutable Seq.

Comment: So, this was the right answer, so I'm going to accept it. I was further confused as if I do: intSeq :+ 4  it returns an instance of IndexedSeq[Int] rather than the IntSeq class defined.

Comment: Well of course it does. If you want to have a narrower return type, you have to overwrite its definition. Or maybe you can start with something. Or you start further up in the inheritance hierarchy. IndexedSeqLike[A, Repr] has a second type parameter where you can specify its own type, so you could instead write IntSeq extends SeqLike[Int, IntSeq]

Comment: I've ended up abandoning defining a collection in order to have a strongly typed collection object (as in, although it is a fake use case, an Ints collection that can only contain instances of Int). I've ended up making my class a wrapper around an existing collection rather a collection itself. Defining custom collections in Scala seems quite hard.